# Is converting a PDF file to Post Script a lossless operation?

Tags: pdf, postscript

I will use `pstops` to do some rearranging of a PDF-file, but first I need to convert it to Post Script.

**Is that a lossless operation?** That is, are the curves in a Post Script file described using the same kind of algorithms as in a PDF or will there be some conversion errors?

Comment: pdf was originally derived from a simplified standardised postscript (as understood by adobe illustrator) so its rendering model of bezier curves is identical although by now there are features in pdf not in postscript (linking and transparency effects at least) although the system may still be able to round trip by using pdfmatk or ad hoc comments in the postscript that are re-converted back to suitable pdf. (But this is all off topic here) you would be better to ask on stackoverflow